# This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key openKey. How to fix errors

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, nsdictionary, setvalue

The source of the error.

```
@objc func selectHeader(sender: UIButton) -> Void {

        var testSection = NSDictionary()
        var openValue = String()

        testSection = self.arrHeader.object(at: sender.tag) as! NSDictionary
        openValue = testSection.value(forKey: self.isOpenKey) as! String


        // value change
        if openValue == "Y" {

            testSection.setValue("N", forKey: self.isOpenKey)  <—— App crash self.isOpenKey == “openKey”
        } else {

           testSection.setValue("Y", forKey: self.isOpenKey)   <—— App crash self.isOpenKey == “openKey”
        }


        let section: NSIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: (sender.tag))
        self.collectionView.reloadSections(section as IndexSet)


}
```

TestSection.setValue crashes with the following error.

2018-02-09 16:43:38.141[10730:2091077] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionarySSSS_ 0x1665dea0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key openKey.'
*** First throw call stack:
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

What is the problem?

Comment: Where is your isOpenKey variable defined? Never use value(:forKey)... It's one way ticket to hell...

Comment: What kind of var is isOpenKey? Looks like a Bool. You can’t use a Bool for a dictionary key.

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let headerKey: String = "headerKey"
    let isOpenKey: String = "openKey"  

I have set this up.

Comment: Okay. So what is the value of testSection at the crash point? If it’s nil that is bad.

Comment: If you take the value of isOpenKey before crash, it will print "N" normally.

Comment: In addition, when you touch the Header section,

headerCell.btnHeader.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectHeader(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

Execute selectHeader func.
 
viewDidLoad-----
From viewDidLoad
        self.arrHeader = NSMutableArray(array: [[headerKey : “aaa”,isOpenKey : "N"],
                                                [headerKey : “bbb”,isOpenKey : "N"],
                                                [headerKey : “ccc”,isOpenKey : "N"]])

Comment: The result of outputting the log in selectHeader.

        testSection = self.arrHeader.object(at: sender.tag) as! NSDictionary
        openValue = testSection.value(forKey: self.isOpenKey) as! String

        print("LOG_1: \(String(describing: self.isOpenKey))")
        print("LOG_2 : \(String(describing: testSection))")
        print("LOG_3 : \(String(describing: sender.tag))")
        print("LOG_4 : \(String(describing: openValue))")

Comment: LOG_1: openKey
LOG_2 : {
    headerKey = "\Ub0b4\Uac00 \Ub4f1\Ub85d\Ud55c \Ucee8\Ud150\Uce20";
    openKey = N;
}
LOG_3 : 0
LOG_4 : N

Comment: What is the `self.arrHeader.object(at: sender.tag)` and why do you convert it to `NSDictionary`?

Comment: Try `testSection["self.isOpenKey"] = "N"`.

Comment: Do not use NSDictionary. Do not use NSIndexSet. Those are Objective-C classes. This is _Swift_. Write your code in Swift. Use Dictionary (and IndexSet) and your problems will vanish because you will have to write correct code.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.
That problem is solved with swiftyJSON. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `NSDictionary` wrong.
First - in response to the comments of @Willeke, you cannot modify an `NSDictionary`, you need a `NSMutableDictionary`. You even better might want to use `Dictionary`.

Then, you should call `setObject:forKey:`, not `setValue:forKey:`

I must admit that this API might be a little confusing, because it is so look-alike:

What you want is to **map** a Dictionary key entry to an object, which is done by `setObject:forKey:`, in your example (with a mutable dictionary): `testSection.setObject("N", forKey: "openKey")`. Using the Swift way with a Swift `Dictionary`, you would write `testSection["openKey"] = "N"`

When using `setValue:forKey:`, you are **Key-Value-Coding**, e.g. you are calling a method ("sending a message") to the `NSDictionary` instance, and the name of the Message is what you provided in the key value. This would result in something like calling `textSection.openKey = "N"`, thus the exeption

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key openKey

In the special case of `NSMutableDictionary`, as @matt mentioned, both `setValue:forKey` and `setObject:forKey` behave the same as long as you do not provide an `NSString` as a key parameter - in that latter case, KVC will be used.

Comment: It is posible to use `valueForKey:` with `NSDictionary` and `setValue:forKey:` with `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: From the documentation of `NSDictionary`: "In general, a key can be any object (provided that it conforms to the NSCopying protocol—see below), but note that when using key-value coding the key must be a string".

Comment: @Willeke: You are right with distinguishing bewenn mutable and non-mutable Dictionarys; nevertheless, `setValue:forKey:` is diametrically opposed to what `setObject:forKey` does, and I think this is what the original poster got mixed.

Comment: "setValue:forKey: is diametrically opposed to what setObject:forKey" `setValue:forKey:` _calls_ `setObject:forKey:`. So they are hardly "diametrically opposed"; they are more like synonymous.

Comment: @matt you are right, but this is _only_ true for `NSMutableDictionary`. In almost all other `NSObject` classes `setValue:forKey:` is intended to provide KVC functionality.

Comment: But we are _talking_ about NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: We should stop talking about `NSMutableDictionary` while talking about Swift 

Comment: Well, _I_ was talking about `NSDictionary` and tried to explain the "key value coding" error. But I think we all agree in just skipping all the NS-Stuff when working with Swift.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.
That problem is solved with swiftyJSON. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the problem?

The "problem" is that you are using NSDictionary in a Swift program, plus you are using key-value coding (`value(forKey:)`, `setValue(_:forKey:)`) all over the place. Stop it. This is Swift, not Objective-C. Use Swift types and Swift means of talking to them.